# c# DirectoryEntry InvokeSet HomeDirectory and HomeDrive, errors

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

I'm trying to modify the Profiles / Home Directory / Home Drive setting for each AD user in a specified OU,

I have below some very basic code that should achieve this feat but is instead throwing the following exception:

> The requested operation did not satisfy one or more constraints
>   associated with the class of the object.

Has anyone had this problem and if so, have a way of fixing it?

Thank you.

```
DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Company,DC=corp,DC=Placeholder,DC=com", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Entry);
Searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";

foreach (SearchResult AdObj in Searcher.FindAll())
{
   Entry.InvokeSet("HomeDirectory", @"\\winfileserver\" + Convert.ToString(AdObj.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]));
   Entry.InvokeSet("HomeDrive", "H");
   Entry.CommitChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   richTextBox1.Text += ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: `InvokeSet` should not be used, see MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invokeset(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using `Entry` which is pointing to your directory root, not the object you found and that's why the call is failing.

I believe you can change your foreach loop to:

```
foreach (SearchResult AdObj in Searcher.FindAll()) {
  DirectoryEntry user = AdObj.GetDirectoryEntry();
  user.InvokeSet("HomeDirectory", @"\\winfileserver\" + Convert.ToString(AdObj.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]));
  user.InvokeSet("HomeDrive", "H");
  user.CommitChanges();
}
```

Comment: ***InvokeSet*** `deprecated` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invokeset(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason to call InvokeSet, also. This is the correct way to do this:

```
foreach (SearchResult AdObj in Searcher.FindAll()) { 
  DirectoryEntry user = AdObj.GetDirectoryEntry(); 
  user.Properties["HomeDirectory"].Value = @"\\winfileserver\" + Convert.ToString(AdObj.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]); 
  user.Properties["HomeDrive"].Value = "H"; 
  user.CommitChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: This is supported by the documentation, `InvokeSet` should **never** be used. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invokeset(v=vs.110).aspx